# I keep getting 'could not get jdbc connection nested exception'

Tags: mysql, jdbc, cas, nested-exceptions

I am trying to use CAS server locally with my local DB, however I keep getting `could not get jdbc connection nested exception` error. I have my deployerconfigcontext setup in the followig way

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/usermanagement</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>root</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The full error i get is

```
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory <Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'<using password:NO>>
```

Comment: Please include the entire stacktrace and full error

Comment: I guess you need to specify the property `password` as well.

Comment: I managed to solve this issue, the problem was that the user root had no password, i assigned a password for root which solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the password for root user, solved the problem